# explode and get the content inside quotes

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am using a method to list a bunch of users/information inside a table row:

```
"3""2""5""pg1"
```

Say this is the data I get, how do I make it so I only retrieve the data inside the quotation marks (as an array). I'm doing it like this because it helps in the long run for programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) if there cannot be a quotation mark inside the value:

```
$string = '"3""2""5""pg1"';
$array = explode( '""', trim( $string, '"'));
```

This [will output](http://viper-7.com/J5ra91):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
    [3] => pg1
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll accept in 12 minutes (when it lets me)

Answer (score 2):

You could use preg_split to break it apart:

```
preg_split("/\"+/", STRING, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Not working because you receive NULL arrays:
$string = '"3""2""5""pg1"'; print_r(preg_split("/\"+/", $string));
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 5
    [4] => pg1
    [5] => 
)

Comment: My fault, PHP has a flag that handles this for you - PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY.  I've added that to the answer.

Comment: But you need once more to explode. Your result:  string(9) "3,2,5,pg1" is not resulted array: add $result = explode(",", $string);

Comment: @MarinSagovac, the code above returns an array correctly.  No need for your explode statement: [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cfk-dsi)

Answer (score 1):

This is not fully answered because I have another some explorations....

> TRIM is not faster as ltrim and rtrim? Look at example...

```
<?php

// FASTEST: 0.13544297218323 ms     
$a1 = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<=100000; $i++) {
$string = '"3""2""5""pg1"';
$array = explode( '""', trim( $string, '"'));
}
$a1e = microtime(true);
$a1r = $a1e-$a1;


// MIDDLE FAST: 0.2419900894165 ms
$a2 = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<=100000; $i++) {
$string = '"3""2""5""pg1"';
$string = rtrim(ltrim(str_replace('""', ',', $string), '"'), '"');
$pieces = explode(',', $string);
}
$a2e = microtime(true);
$a2r = $a2e-$a2;

// MIDDLE 0.20940399169922 ms!
$a3 = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<=100000; $i++) {
$re = preg_split("/\"+/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $pieces = explode(',', $re[0]);
}
$a3e = microtime(true);
$a3r = $a3e-$a3;

echo $a1r."\r\n"; 
echo $a2r."\r\n"; 
echo $a3r."\r\n";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for testing this. Looks like I take the trophy.

Comment: This isn't a proper benchmark. Not only are you timing a variable assignment in the first two cases and not the third, but this is a single execution, where optimizations will tarnish your results. [This](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gq3Gzx) is a proper benchmark. Take both methods, isolate them within functions, and call the functions 1,000,000 times to get a true metric of their runtime. Now you'll see the first version running almost 50% faster than the second. Intuitively, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Also, you can remove your added `explode` from the `preg_split` example.  With a correct pattern, this is not necessary.  See link for example: [phpFiddle - preg_replace](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cfk-dsi)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant way to do it:

```
<?php

$string = '"3""2""5""pg1"';

$string = rtrim(ltrim(str_replace('""', ',', $string), '"'), '"');

$pieces = explode(',', $string);

print_r($pieces);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
    [3] => pg1
)
```

[See the demo](http://codepad.org/29h4P7Sd)